# Once buy condition is true stay true until sell condition is true

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In a nutshell: Once buy condition is true, stay true until selling condition is true, even if buy condition becomes false in between.

Basically I'm using 2 ema strategy and want to display only stoploss ema

```
maSmall = ta.ema(low, 50)      //1st 50 ema with low as source
maLarge = ta.ema(high, 50)      //2nd 50 ema with high as source

buyCondition = close > maLarge
shortCondition = close < maSmall
```

Basically I want ***buyCondition*** to stay true until ***shortCondition*** become true.

But when price is in between both ema my ***buyCondition*** on currrent candle **becomes false**.

I don't want it to let it happen and want ***buyCondition*** to become false only when close < maSmall.

Note: I'll use these condition in color variable when plotting the ema's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pinescript, variables are overwritten on every bar. In your case, `buyCondition` will be set to `false` on every bar where the condition `close > maLarge` is not met, regardless if `shortCondition` is true or not.

To fix this, you'll need to use the `var` keyword:

> Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn’t include the keyword var, results in the value of the variable being overwritten with every update of the data. Contrary to that, when assigning variables with the keyword var, they can “keep the state” despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within if-expressions are met.

For example:

```
maSmall = ta.ema(low, 50)
maLarge = ta.ema(high, 50)

var buyCondition = false
var shortCondition = false

if close > maLarge
    buyCondition := true
    shortCondition := false

if close < maSmall
    buyCondition := false
    shortCondition := true
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked and for explanation. 